# No Fingerprint Button in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: ubuntu, fingerprint

I've updated on Ubuntu 19.04, hoping to unlock my Acer Spin 5 with the Elantech Fingerprint Sensor (04f3: 0c03). When I go to the user settings, there is no button that I can use to add fingers.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `fprint` fingerprint program which [supports](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html) your Elantech Fingerprint Sensor.

The packages are available in the [standard "universe"](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=disco&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=fprint).

To install it, run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fprintd libfprint0 libpam-fprintd fprint-demo
```

See: https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fprint

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I add the ppa, then I get this error message: [See at pastebin](https://pastebin.com/jW8PFUP4)

Comment: Remove the ppa again (`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:fingerprint/fprint`) and install it from the standard sources as described. I only added the link for a description. Viel Glück!

Comment: Ok, I did. Now I have the software. When I open fprint_demo, I get the message: "No devices found".